# phpbb show custom field for activating newly registered users

Tags: phpbb3

I added in my phpBB 3.1.3 forum a custom profile field which has to be filled in if someone registers on my forum. I want that this field can be seen only by administrators. Therefore, I checked the following options:

[image]

I also require that newly registered users have to be activated by an administrator. Whether a user gets activated depends on the text that he puts into his profile field. However, the profile field does not appear in the inactive users list in the ACP, nor does it show up if I click on the user. How can I find the custom profile field for inactive users?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top right drop down box that is currently showing `Overview` change this to `Profile` and hit `Go`. This will show custom profile fields at the bottom of the page.